# C++: redefinition of a 'classname'

Tags: c++, header-files, ambiguity, redefinition

I'm writing a code describing a complex variable and a real variable.

i've included the header file which seems to produce a conflict between the .hpp file and the .cpp file.

They are similiar and I can't track down from where the redefinition happen.

**solver.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

class RealVariable
    {
        public:
        std::complex<double>c;
        RealVariable(double d);
        RealVariable();
   };

    class ComplexVariable
    {
        public:
        std::complex <double>d;
        ComplexVariable(double d1,double d2);
        ComplexVariable();

    };
```

**solver.cpp**

```
#include "solver.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

class RealVariable
    {
        public:
        std::complex<double>c;
        RealVariable(double d)
          {
            c.imag(0);
            c.real(d);
          }
        RealVariable(){}
   };

    class ComplexVariable
    {
        public:
        std::complex <double>d;
        ComplexVariable(double d1,double d2)
         {
          d.imag(d2);
          d.real(d1);
         }
        ComplexVariable(){}

    };
```

On the surface, the definition
in .hpp and .cpp file looks identical(at least to me).

I get this error in the terminal:
[image]

Comment: In c++ you generally dont redefine the classes in the C++ files, you just define the functions

Answer (score 1):

In your CPP file only the implementations should go.

```
#include "solver.hpp"

RealVariable::RealVariable(double d)
{
    c.imag(0);
    c.real(d);
}

RealVariable::RealVariable()
{
}

ComplexVariable::ComplexVariable(double d1,double d2)
{
  d.imag(d2);
  d.real(d1);
}

ComplexVariable::ComplexVariable()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two definitions of the same class, even if they are 'identical'. Your `.hpp` file provides the class definitions, so you can't have those (again) in your `.cpp` file.

Instead, just provide the required definitions of the member functions in your `.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include "solver.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

RealVariable::RealVariable(double d)
{
    c.imag(0);
    c.real(d);
}

RealVariable::RealVariable(){} // Though this could easily go 'inline' in the .hpp file

ComplexVariable::ComplexVariable(double d1,double d2)
{
    d.imag(d2);
    d.real(d1);
}

ComplexVariable::ComplexVariable(){} // Again, could readily be inline in the header
```